# Не работает условие проверки уже зарегистрированных пользователя?

Tags: php, mysql

мне нужно проверка на уже зарегистрированных пользователей, по условие счетчик, если пользователь уникален он должен быть зарегистрирован и переход в админку (самописную), если нет, а повторяется то должно появляться сообщение, что логин занят и блокировать переход. Сейчас при дублировании логина, идёт просто переход не срабатывает условие.

```
  require('connect.php');
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];


    $sql = 'SELECT count(id) as count FROM users WHERE username=?'; 
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $query->execute([$username]);
    $count_users = $query->fetch(); 
    if ((int)$count_users['count'] === 0) { 
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `email`)
      VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
    } else {
      echo "<script>alert('Логин уже занят')</script>"; 
    }
        
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("Location: /");
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

  $conn->close();
 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ну а ты посмотрел __что__ у тебя в `$count_users`? Ну и по логике - у тебя `$conn->query($sql)` выполняется __всегда__.

Comment: Спасибо я убрал  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE), переход опять работает и условие не срабатывает. В чем может быть ошибка ?

Comment: Какое условие не срабатывает?

Comment: if ((int)$count_users['count'] === 0) { 
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `email`)
      VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
    } else {
      echo "<script>alert('Логин уже занят')</script>"; 
    }

Comment: Опиши, что __должно происходить__, что __сейчас происходит__ и обнови код в задаче, если нужно. Додумывать, что идет не так у тебя в коде, никто не собирается.

Comment: Я же вроде расписал все понятно и чётко, проверка на уже зарегистрированных пользователей. Сейчас идёт переход на страницу и дублируются в БД, новый юзер с одинаковыми логинами. Я хочу это пофиксить и условие должно проверять дублируется логин или нет нового юзера. Так понятно ?

Comment: Ну полчается что insert-запрос надо делать только если `$count_users['count'] === 0`, так?

Comment: Да, всё правильно

Comment: Ну а я вижу что в представленном коде запрос выполняется всегда. Вот ты пишешь что что-то там поправил. А что именно - как я узнаю?